# Foreach non-unique rows to obtain a related key

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image]

Can such SELECTion be made? Based only on QTZ_USERS UUID can I "foreach" all memberships with GROUP_ID's to find the GROUP_ID with the highest prority?

How can I approach that?

Comment: Can you not order by priority desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want details from all the tables then join them together and to a sub query to get the latest priority for each user.

Something like the following (although select the actual columns you want rather than use SELECT *).

```
SELECT *
FROM QTZ_USERS u
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIPS m
ON u.UUID = m.UUID
INNER JOIN GROUPS g
ON m.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT m.UUID, MAX(g.PRIORITY) AS max_priority
    FROM MEMBERSHIPS m
    INNER JOIN GROUPS g
    ON m.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID
    GROUP BY m.UUID
) sub0
ON m.UUID = sub0.UUID
AND g.PRIORITY = sub0.max_priority
```

Answer (score 1):

Principially you do this with `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions, here [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max).

```
SELECT
    m.UUID,
    MAX(g.PRIORITY)
FROM
    memberships m    
INNER JOIN
    groups  g
ON 
    m.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID
GROUP BY
    m.UUID;
```

If you need the GROUP_ID, then you can use a subselect

```
SELECT
    m.UUID,
    g.GROUP_ID
FROM
    memberships m    
INNER JOIN
      groups  g
ON 
    m.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE
    g.priority = (
         SELECT
             MAX(g2.priority)
         FROM
             groups g2
         WHERE
             g.group_id = g2.group_id
         GROUP BY
             g2.group_id
    );
```